# Rails undefined method `find_or_create_from_auth_hash'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, omniauth

My sessions_controller is as follows:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
require 'omniauth-facebook'
require 'omniauth'
def create
@user = User.find_or_create_from_auth_hash(auth_hash)
self.current_user = @user
redirect_to '/'
end

protected

def auth_hash
request.env['omniauth.auth']
end
end
```

So... it's THERE isn't it?

Here's my users.rb file:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
acts_as_voter
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
# :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

# Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
# attr_accessible :title, :body
has_many :posts
has_many :tasks
end
```

And my routes file:

```
LiquidAdmin::Application.routes.draw do
devise_for :users

get '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'

resource :sessions, :only => :create

get "home/bandwall"
get "home/index"
root :to => "home#index"
```

So where's the problem? "auth_hash" is clearly defined... The SessionsController is loading... so why is it complaining about no method for find_or_create_from_auth_hash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Rails 3.2, the method you'll want to use is called [`first_or_create`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create):

```
User.where(auth_hash: auth_hash).first_or_create
```

According to the [Rails 3.2 release notes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_2_release_notes.html#active-record):

> Add first_or_create, first_or_create!, first_or_initialize methods to
>   Active Record. This is a better approach over the old
>   find_or_create_by dynamic methods because it's clearer which arguments
>   are used to find the record and which are used to create it.

Given this, the following is made possible through the query:

```
User.where(auth_hash: auth_hash).first_or_create(foo: 'bar') # Assuming no other User entries exist
#=> #<User id: 1, auth_hash: "your_auth_hash", foo: "bar">

User.where(auth_hash: auth_hash).first_or_create(foo: 'baz')
#=> #<User id: 1, auth_hash: "your_auth_hash", foo: "bar">
```

Comment: Ok that worked.  I changed the line to @user = User.where(auth_hash: auth_hash).first_or_create but now I'm getting this error: "SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: auth_hash.provider: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "auth_hash"."provider" = 'facebook' AND "auth_hash"."uid" = '672086173' AND "auth_hash"."info" = '--- !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash::InfoHash"

Comment: You need to create a migration for a `provider` on your `AuthHash` model. From command line, try `rails g migration AddProviderToAuthHash provider:string`, then running `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: If this answer works (as you and others have indicated it does), would you kindly consider accepting it as correct? I'm happy to troubleshoot your continued problem (see my prior comment), but it's clearly more myopic in scope than your original question. Since this answer correctly addressed your original question, it'd help other users if you were to accept it as correct.

Comment: Sorry. Thought I did. :) DONE!

Comment: Seriously? You've got like a 12,000+ reputation… the hell with that guy/girl.

Answer (score 2):

Given that this question is based on OmniAuth, I think a better answer would be:

```
@user = User.where(auth_hash).first_or_create
```

or if in Rails version greater than 4.1.14

```
@user = User.where(uid: auth_hash[:uid], provider: auth_hash[:provider]).first_or_create
```

`auth_hash` is not a field in the `User` model, but rather a `Hash` of fields that could be on the `User` model.